# Civicrm Failed upgrade

Tags: civicrm-home

Have Civicrm 5.12.4 and wished to upgrade to 5.14.0

On running database upgrade part failed right at the end with:

> An error has occurred. 0 Class 'CRM_Sparkpost' not found

When checking sparkpost with Civi menu:
Super User->Configure CiviCRM->System Settings->Outbound Email(SparkPost)
failed to take me to the SparkPost menu

So, disabled and then re-enabled the SparkPost exstension. Now the SparkPost menu above works.

Although the above seemed to work, CiviCRM still complained about needing an update to 5.14.0, despite it reporting that version at the status line at the bottom.

So, decided to test upgrade again from scratch, using a copy of today's live database - this time disabling SparkPost extension first.

Now the database upgrade just stops immediately with message:

> [Executed: Cleanup old files
>
> CiviCRM is now broken!

Tried again from scratch without first disabling SparkPost - same problem.

Any ideas?

ubuntu server 16.04.1
php 7.1.30
Joomla 3.9.6
CiviCRM 5.12.4

Comment: possibly a duplicate of https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/30975/upgrade-from-civicrm-5-12-4-to-5-13-5-generates-sparkpost-php-fatal-error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upgrade from CiviCRM 5.12.4 to 5.13.5 generates Sparkpost PHP fatal error](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/30975/upgrade-from-civicrm-5-12-4-to-5-13-5-generates-sparkpost-php-fatal-error)

Answer (score 0):

To confirm this is now fixed in the latest version available of the sparkpost extension available here: https://github.com/cividesk/com.cividesk.email.sparkpost